# Use of "also" in a sentence

Tags: conjunctions

I have a doubt about the use of **also**. 
For example, let us suppose that a document needs to be signed by two persons: one person has already signed; the other one hasn't did it yet.
So is it correct to use "also" in the following sentence

> "I am waiting for it, so that Mary can **also** sign it" ?

or it could be preferable to use another conjunctions to explain these condition/situation?

Thank you for helping me

Comment: That usage is fine. You could also say "... so that Mary can sign it **also**" or ".. so that Mary can sign it **too**."

Answer (score 1):

The two adverbs *also* and *too*, both meaning *in addition to* are interchangeable in many sentences but *too* is preferable here.

To write: "...so that Mary too can sign it." makes is clear that somebody else has signed the document and that it now awaits Mary's signature.

If you use *also*, the sentence could be construed to mean that Mary had already read the document but she had now to sign it as well. This presumably is not what you intend.

Note that your question is badly phrased. It should read: "....the other one hasn't DONE it yet." And the word *conjunctions* should be singular.

Comment: Thank you, Ronald. If I use a passive form (for example: "the forms need to be signed and approved by Mary and John"), where should I put the conjunction "also/too", in order to make clear that somebody else has signed the forms, but Mary and John have not yet?

Comment: @a.rimbaud You could insert *also/too* before *Mary* or after *John*.